# Get the common values between two text files

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

I'm just trying to get the common values from two distinct files called `file1.txt` and `file2.txt` where I'm using Python's `set` method to get the results and this works.

However, I'm looking forward to see if there is better way to do this.

```
#!/grid/common/pkgs/python/v3.6.1/bin/python3
def common_member():
    a_set = dataset1
    b_set = dataset2
    if (a_set & b_set):
        print(a_set & b_set)
    else:
        print("No common elements")

with open('file1.txt', 'r') as a:
        dataset1 = set(a)
with open('file2.txt', 'r') as b:
    dataset2 = set(b)

common_member()
```

#### file1.txt

```
teraform101
azure233
teraform221
teraform223
teraform224
```

#### file2.txt

```
teraform101
azure109
teraform223
teraform226
teraform225
azure233
```

#### Result:

```
{ 'teraform101\n', 'azure233\n', 'teraform223\n' }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Global variables (`dataset1` and `dataset2`) are bad.  I'd rather see you write no function at all than a function that accepts its inputs through global variables:

```
with open('file1.txt') as file1, open('file2.txt') as file2:
    print((set(file1) & set(file2)) or "No common elements")
```

If you do write a function, then it should accept its inputs as parameters.  Name the function's parameters however you want, but avoid unnecessary reassignments like `a_set = dataset1` and `b_set = dataset2`.

```
def print_common_members(a, b):
    """
    Given two sets, print the intersection, or "No common elements".
    """
    print((a & b) or "No common elements")

with open('file1.txt') as file1, open('file2.txt') as file2:
    dataset1 = set(file1)
    dataset2 = set(file2)
    print_common_members(dataset1, dataset2)
```

Comment: This is indeed a great answer.

Comment: in case we need the resulting values into a new line , how could we do that  into this code itself

Comment: @newTOcode: Assign `common_members = a & b` and then do with that variable whatever you want.

Comment: @Graipher, thnx for your valuable inputs,  its solved with using `join` method as `print('\n'.join(s.strip('\n') for s in a & b) or "No common element")`